# Semantic differences

Tags: semantics

what are the semantic differences between the following sentences:

I'd appreciate it if you'd share some of your thoughts...

I'd appreciate it if you shared some of your thoughts...

Thanks

Comment: Pretty much identical.  There may be slight differences depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Ngram chart of "would appreciate if" (blue line) versus "would appreciate it if" (red line):

[image]

As you can see, the latter formulation is far more common. That's because idiomatically it has been the standard wording (since 1900) for expressing thoughts along the line of "I would appreciate [it] if you'd share some of your thoughts."

A look at the individual matches that the Google Books search returned for the two phrases reveals that virtually all of the matches for "would appreciate it if" follow the model of your first example sentence, whereas some of the matches for "would appreciate if" are false positives. For example:

- If the stock of bullion in the world increased in the same ratio with the property of the world, the standard of value would be invariable; if more slowly, it **would appreciate; if** more rapidly, it would depreciate. [[1852](https://books.google.com/books?id=G2NHAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA2&dq=%22would+appreciate+if%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjox-vdsojWAhXqgFQKHdjFAEUQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22would%20appreciate%20if%22&f=false)]
- There is a broad range of delightful belles lettres, which I am sure you **would appreciate if** you would make yourself acquainted with it. [[1865](https://books.google.com/books?id=AU9DAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA191&dq=%22would+appreciate+if%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgnef9tYjWAhUIiFQKHU_RAaI4FBDoAQgnMAA#v=onepage&q=%22would%20appreciate%20if%22&f=false)]
- The University wanted money to pay its expenses. It could not very well wait for twenty or even five years for the purpose of seeing how the value of this scrip **would appreciate, if** at all. [[1890](https://books.google.com/books?id=djOikAhtJ-QC&pg=PA786&dq=%22would+appreciate+if%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8zOextYjWAhWoj1QKHX3cBF84ChDoAQg8MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22would%20appreciate%20if%22&f=false)]
- There are many things that my modesty would not allow me to write about, that I believe you **would appreciate if** you were only to see them. [[1897](https://books.google.com/books?id=AzkbAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA136&dq=%22would+appreciate+if%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHpJDptIjWAhVM-lQKHVZnAr4Q6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=%22would%20appreciate%20if%22&f=false)]
- Yes, that is the doctrine of *Ackroyd* v. *Smithson*. Simple, is it not, and one that you **would appreciate if** you chanced to be A.'s heir; but one you would be inclined to cavil at, if you were one of A.'s next of kin, and not his heir! [[1906](https://books.google.com/books?id=G4JQAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA88&dq=%22would+appreciate+if%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjox-vdsojWAhXqgFQKHdjFAEUQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=%22would%20appreciate%20if%22&f=false)]
- That is one of the advantages that the profession **would appreciate—if** they had an eminent man as a permanent head, rather than having to refer frequently to someone who by chance was placed through his political position at the head of the bar? [[1908](https://books.google.com/books?id=whI6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA34&dq=%22would+appreciate+if%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjox-vdsojWAhXqgFQKHdjFAEUQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22would%20appreciate%20if%22&f=false)]
- If the Commonwealth would consider withdrawing from the whole field of income taxation there would be a saving which the public **would appreciate. If** it would do so, we would be willing to face the difficulties of approaching the people to make good the revenue that the Commonwealth had relinquished. [[1923](https://books.google.com/books?id=cC8tAQAAMAAJ&q=%22would+appreciate+if%22&dq=%22would+appreciate+if%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi03bDmtojWAhVph1QKHeSCCLY4ChDoAQgzMAM)]

So the difference in relevant published usage is probably somewhat greater than the Ngram chart suggests. Nevertheless, from about 1910 onward, the vast majority of instances of "would appreciate if" **are** on point—and usage of that form appears to be increasing moderately in published writing (and probably much more vigorously in spoken English, where copy editors aren't around to force wayward expressions to conform to the idiomatically favored form).

To sum up,

> I'd appreciate it if you'd share some of your thoughts.

remains the more common idiomatic form of the two that you ask about, but

> I'd appreciate if you shared some of your thoughts.

is also widely used, and most people wouldn't dream of challenging its use on grounds that it is not the preferred idiomatic form. In any event, no one will have any trouble understanding either form of expression.